# Django + MySQL : Round Robin Update of Same Table Columns

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

My Model is sort of like

```
Spot 
    spot_1 = 1/0
    spot_2 = 1/0
    spot_3 = 1/0
    spot_4 = 1/0
    spot_5 = 1/0
    spot_6 = 1/0
```

Sort of like Round Robin Database, assuming the `spot_1` represents Current Month, `spot_2` represents the previous month, and so on. So if current month is  June, so

```
Jun  = spot_1  
May  = spot_2  
Apr  = spot_3  
Mar  = spot_4  
Feb  = spot_5  
Jan  = spot_6
```

So at the End of the Month of June, and Begining of July, this would be represented as

```
July = spot_1  
Jun  = spot_2  
May  = spot_3  
Apr  = spot_4  
Mar  = spot_5  
Feb  = spot_6
```

So the Values should be carried forward as well. Currently I am looping through the complete QuerySet and making the values to Move Forward.

How can this be achieved with Single `update()` statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`F`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F) expressions:

```
from django.db.models import F

Spot.objects.all().update(spot_2=F('spot_1'), spot_3=F('spot_2'), ...)
```

Comment: MySQL Raw query should look like this


`update spot set spot_2=spot_1, spot_3=spot_2 where 1`


How would the F() expression look like ?

Comment: More or less the same: `update spot set spot_2=spot.spot_1, spot_3=spot.spot_2`

Comment: I did this, but in a reverse order
`Spot.objects.all().update(spot_6=F('spot_5'), spot_5=F('spot_4'), ...)`

what is happening is, all the `spots` are getting filled with the `latest spot` value ?

Comment: I guess I have to loop through and update one spot at a time. Starting the loop from largest spot to minimum spot. That is not something that looks cool, but does the job.

Comment: I have another question, regarding transactions, if you can provide some insight, I am not able to wrap my head around it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992662/django-1-6-transaction-management-on-large-list-of-model-objects